# How do I get Facebook recent post in our website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am working with codeigniter but i don't want to use library to get recent post from facebook. Is there any way to get recent post from facebook using javascript. I tried with some code using javascript but i am not getting the result.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not want to use a library? JS works that way in most cases. Use a library or module. If it does not exist, code it and publish it.

If you don't want to use a library, check the facebook API yourself and request the data by using AJAX calls.

https://developers.facebook.com/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started